# Make textbox be on both sides

Tags: html, css

I want to have something like this

[image: see img]

instead I

[image: get this result]

My html code is this 
`

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <form class="quote" action="javascript:void(0);"> 
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <article class="goright">

      <input type="name" name="Name" placeholder="" style="width: 140px"><br>

      <input type="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="" style="width: 140px"><br>

      <input type="Place" name="Place" placeholder="" style="width: 140px"><br>

      </article>
      <aside id="sidebar">

      <textarea type="name" name="Name" placeholder="" style="height: 80px"></textarea> <br>

      </aside>
      </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
    .modal {
        display: none; 
        position: relative; 
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 100px; 
        left: 0;
        top: -300px;
        float: right;
        width: 40%; 
        height: 40%; 
        overflow: auto; 
    }
        .modal-content {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin:auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%;
        -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
        animation-name: animatetop;
        animation-duration: 0.4;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    article#goright
    {   
        float: right;
    }
    aside#sidebar
    {
        float: left;
    }
    aside#sidebar .quote input, aside#sidebar .quote textarea
    {
        width: 90%;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

so I tried to look up this thing here but I could not find an answer that works for me, I tried a lot of variations but nothing really works and I can not get the result, I only managed to get one side that is floated right and aside bar that is left but aside is under previous bar.
So, can you give me a hint or code that can help me achieve the desired result ?

Comment: set width 48% #sidebar and #goright

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Are you open to using Flexbox?

Comment: check my answer . see snippet below

Comment: I understood it thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5xw7ssa4/

But you have some mistakes in your css:

- Height should not be in %.
- Both container must float to right.
- Do not forget to `clear:both` after last floating element.
- `article#goright` must be `article.goright`
- In your html you have `type="name"` for example. It must be `type="text"`.

Comment: The element is not allowed to float.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `<aside>` and other CSS tweaks to achieve the structure.

Just move the `<textarea>` above the `<input>` tags and add a `float:left` class  and `float:right` class to them respectively.

The width of the form is inherited from the `.modal` class.

Also `<input>` tags `type` attribute used are invalid. Supporting `type` attributes are as mentioned in: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Also `<textarea>` does not have a `type` attribute by default.

```css
.modal {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
}

.align-left {
  float: left;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <form class="quote" action="javascript:void(0);">
        <textarea name="Name" placeholder="Textarea" style="height: 80px" class="align-left"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Input A" style="width: 140px" class="align-right" />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Input B" style="width: 140px" class="align-right" />
        <input type="text" name="Place" placeholder="Input C" style="width: 140px" class="align-right" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you're trying to achieve -

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.textarea-wrapper,
.input-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.textarea-wrapper {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}

.input {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="textarea-wrapper">
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Text 1">
     <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Text 2">
     <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Text 2">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a link. 
https://codepen.io/aphextwix/pen/MmZxjR

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you should review both your html markup and css as well bellow are my suggestions

css

```
.modal {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    height: 123px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
        .modal-content {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin:auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%;
        -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
        animation-name: animatetop;
        animation-duration: 0.4;

    }
form {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
.close{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 3;
}
/*a classis identified by a "." an id is identified by an "#" so article#goright is wrong you should have wrote article.goright*/
    article.goright {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
   aside#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
/* .quote is the form class  aside is inside the form so instead of aside#sidebar .quote textarea you should write  .quote aside#sidebar textarea */ 
    .quote aside#sidebar  input, .quote aside#sidebar textarea
    {
        width: 90%;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    article.goright input {
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}
/*very important to solve the issue*/
.clear{
width: 100%;
height: 0;
clear: both;
float: none;
}
```

html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Testing Page</title>
</head>

<body style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <form class="quote" action="javascript:void(0);"> 
      <span class="close">&times;</span>

      <aside id="sidebar">

      <textarea type="name" name="Name" placeholder="" style="height: 80px"></textarea> <br>

      </aside>
      <article class="goright">

      <input type="name" name="Name" placeholder=""><br>

      <input type="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder=""><br>

      <input type="Place" name="Place" placeholder=""><br>

      </article>
       <!-- this is the div you need to have myModal div cover the div inside it since they are floating left -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
      </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```